# DAX retrieve rows with max value within a group based on date filter

Tags: powerbi, ssas, dax, ssas-tabular

i have the following table with some sample data similar to what we have in our model:

[image]

there will be a date filter called "As Of Date" that will be selected by the user.  I will need to create a new measure that filters the above table using these rules each time:

1. rows where reserve date <= the As Of Date selected by the user
2. rows that are in "Approved" status
3. for each combination of Claim Id, Damage Id, and Location Id, get the row with the latest sequence number
4. sum the reserve value column

so based on the sample data above, if the user select an As Of Date of `8-1-2020`, the measure should sum the `Reserve Value` from the following rows that meet the criteria:

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is a measure that would return `900` as that is the sum of the reserve values for the rows that meet the criteria, as listed in the second table above.

Thanks

scott

Comment: Are you looking for a measure to put into a dashboard or for a DAX query to output the table?

Comment: Oh sorry I see you want the summed value and the table is an intermediate step.

Comment: yes iamdave, i need the measure to return the sum of the reserve values based on the logic provided.  The table needs to be filtered to the rows that match the criteria provided before the sum happens